# Linking/importing externalized source code in org-mode

Tags: r, org-mode, knitr, literate-programming, reproducible-research

This [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v46/i03) inspired me to check out Emac's [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) a bit and currently I try to assess what's more suitable for writing my documents: [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)/[Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) (I'm mainly using R to do my programming) or org-mode.

What I really like about knitr is the option to [externalize the actual source](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) (watch out: the declaration of labels/names in the R script seems to have changed from `## ---- label -------` to `## @knitr label`; see `?read_chunk`) and "link" them to the actual literate programming/reproducible research document (as opposed to actually **writing** the code in that very document):

"Import" with

```
<<import-external, cache=FALSE>>=
read_chunk('foo-bar.R') # has label/name 'foo-bar'
@
```

and "re-use" by referencing the respective labels with

```
<<foo-bar>>=
@
```

### Question

Is this also possible in org-mode or am I bound to putting the actual code into the `.org` document?

I found [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-With-Source-Code.html), but I did not find any specific notion of linking/importing external source code files **and** be able to execute them by having the linked code inside

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R
<linked code>
#+END_SRC
```

### Background

I do see that this approach might contrast the general paradigm of literate programing to some extend. But I like to work in a somewhat "atomic" style and thus it feels more natural to me to keep the files separated at first and then mash everything together dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would named code blocks help?

```
 #+NAME: foo-bar
 #+BEGIN_SRC R
   source(foo-bar.R)
 #+END_SRC
```

And then evaluate (i.e. load) the code when you actually need it:

```
 #+CALL: foo-bar()
```

See [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html#Evaluating-code-blocks) for more details.

Comment: "Duh" to myself! Of course, that should work! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Just to make sure, though: that way the code in `foo-bar.R` is expected to be a `function` (as opposed to other types of "loose" expressions), right? Because seems that in `#+CALL:` you actually calling a function. Or is the `()` part just the org-mode way of passing/"overwriting" arbitrary code elements to named code blocks?

Comment: The name in the `#+CALL:` is what you used in `#+NAME:`, it has nothing to do with what is actually in your R code (it can be anything). The `()` part is the way to pass parameters to the named code block where you could have defined header parameters (e.g. `:var n=2`), then you can do `#+CALL: foo-bar(n=4)` (see that section from the Org mode manual).

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for clarifying that. Then I think that should perfectly do!